# react-google-maps: How can I dynamically style the Google container (.pac-container) of multiple StandaloneSearchBox components?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-places-api, react-google-maps

The container of the Google Places searchbox that is created with [react-google-maps](https://tomchentw.github.io/react-google-maps/#standalonesearchbox) has class called `.pac-container`. Now, I've got multiple of those on one page and I want to style them differently. For example, one should drop upwards, another one downwards.

How can I achieve this? I can't pass down a class name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can wrap you StandAloneSearchBox with with a parent wrapper.

```
<div className="ancestor1"><StandAloneSearchBox></div>
<div className="ancestor2"><StandAloneSearchBox></div>
```

And

```
.ancestor1 .pac-container
.ancestor2 .pac-container
```

Maybe you need to put inside `StandAloneSearchBox` because sometimes google maps ignore parent div. Do let me know if the issue still persists.

Comment: I didn't try it yet but this sounds like the right thing to do

Comment: sorry, did this work? I'm trying and it's not working for me :(